# How to send a message to the number using the alert view send button in iPhone Swift?

Tags: swift

I have created one alert view with title as number, body as message, send and cancel button. Once I click on send button, the message should be sent to that particular number witch is there in the title. I'm using iOS Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `MFMessageViewController` class, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html).